# Iterating over a text file in bash and rounding each number

Tags: bash, text

My file looks like this

```
0 0 1 0.2 1 1
1 1 0.8 0.1 1
0.2 0.4 1 0 1
```

And I need to a create a new output file

```
0 0 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1
```

i.e. if the number is greater than 0.5, it is rounded up to 1, and if it less than 0.5, it is rounded down to 0 and put into a new file.

The file is quite large, with ~ 1400000000 values. I would quite like to write a bash script to do this.

I am guessing the best way to do this would be to iterate over each value in a `for` loop, with an `if` statement inside which tests whether the number is greater or less than 0.5 and then prints 0 or 1 dependent.

The pseudocode would look like this, but my bash isn't great so - before you tell my it isnt syntatically correct, I already know

```
#!/bin/bash
#reads in each line
while read p; do
  #loops through each number in each line
  for i in p; do
  #tests if each number is greater than or equal to 0.5 and prints accordingly
    if [i => 0.5]
    then 
        print 1
    else
        print 0
    fi 

done < test.txt >
```

I'm not really sure how to do this. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: You'll find bash to be quite slow. Use a more general purpose scripting language like python, awk, perl, ...

Comment: To help you with bash syntax, paste your code into https://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: Another critical problem: bash cannot do anything with floating point numbers.

Comment: so , `0.5` should be rounded to `1` ?

Comment: If you really have 1.4 billion values to deal with, you would find a short program in a compiled language like C, orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: OK,thanks for the heads up with that. It seems to be taking quite a long time using bash. I will have a go with a C program. thank you.

Comment: @sahwahn - you might try [Round Billion Floating-point Values to Integer](https://pastebin.com/15R7UGTe)

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{ 
   for( i=1; i<=NF; i++ )
      $i = $i<0.5 ? 0 : 1
}1' input_file > output_file
```

`$i = $i<0.5 ? 0 : 1` changes each field to `0` or `1` and `{...}1` will print the line with the changed values afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

another `awk` without loops...

```
$ awk -v RS='[ \n]' '{printf ($1>=0.5) RT}' file

0 0 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1
```

if the values are not between 0 and 1, you may want to change to

```
$ awk -v RS='[ \n]' '{printf "%.0f%s", $1, RT}' file
```

note that default rounding is to the even (i.e. 0.5 -> 0, but 1.5 -> 2).  If you want always to round up

```
$ awk -v RS='[ \n]' '{i=int($1); printf "%d%s", i+(($1-i)>=0.5), RT}' file
```

should take of non-negative numbers.  For negatives, there are again two alternatives, round towards zero or towards negative infinity.

Comment: Nice. (this is a filler)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one in Perl using regex and look-ahead:

```
$ perl -p -e 's/0(?=\.[6789])/1/g;s/\.[0-9]+//g' file
0 0 1 0 1 1
1 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 0 1
```

I went with the *if it less than 0.5, it is rounded down to 0* part.